# Where to find GA Conversion tracking code in 2014 version?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions

In the newest version of Google Analytics (2014), where do I find the conversion tracking code? The following resource doesn't tell me and I can't figure it out.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033158?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Click on "admin" in the top menu then in the properties - the centre section - the third item down is "tracking info" click it to open and you will see "tracking code"

Answer (score 1):

Unlike AdWords there is no specific (extra) snippet that you add to pages to signify a conversion.

Analytics conversions can be much broader (up to 20 per view/profile) and, ideally, you should [track macro and micro conversions](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/excellent-analytics-tip-13-measure-macro-and-micro-conversions/).

Since you are new to this, start with an obvious one. Many sites redirect users to a "thank you" page after submitting a contact form (or if e-commerce, a 'success' page).

Under **admin**, go to '**view**' settings, then '**goals**.' Under '**Goal Setup**' select '**Custom**,' then (next screen) select '**Destination**' and enter the relative URL of your goal (the page viewed)...for instance `/thank-you/`

If there is a value or a funnel you can set those up too.

There can be more to it but once you set one up the rest will come easily.